# Custom View with shadow going out of circle background

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-custom-view, android-shape

I'm trying to create a custom view with shadow text.

[image]

As you can see the shadow is going out of circle. I want shadow to be inside of the circle.

The circle is the background of the view. Which I'm setting from xml

```
android:background="@drawable/background"
```

here is my onDraw method

```
override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {

    paint.color = shadowColor
    for (shadow in shadowList) {
        canvas.drawText(text, width / 2 - textBound.width() / 2 + shadow.dx, height / 2 + textBound.height() / 2 + shadow.dy, paint)
    }

    paint.color = textColor
    canvas.drawText(text, (width / 2 - textBound.width() / 2).toFloat(), (height / 2 + textBound.height() / 2).toFloat(), paint)
}
```

What I want to achieve is the shadow to be inside of circle.

Answer (score 0):

If the background drawable matches the size of your view. You have to find the radius of the circle in your case, you should take the value of half of the view's width or height. Then rather than drawing all shadows in the shadowList, you should only draw shadows sitting in the circle. In order to calculate it you can use bottom-right corner of your view. The distance of the corner to the center point must be equal or lower than the radius of the circle I mentioned above.